# PHP MySQL Compare $row's dates from today

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am wondering if it is possible to compare dates in all $row's from a while loop to today's date. Let me explain.

I have created this table shown in this image:
[image: Betting History]

I have created this table through joining several tables, and actually have a while loop inside a while loop (which is how I got multiple games to show on one row, but only one wager amount per row.

What I want to do is compare the dates of each of the individual games to today's date, to list if the parlay is active or not (in this image, they would all not be active, but that's not the point).

I want to take today's date and if it is less than all the dates of the games, then Active == 'Future', or if today's date is in between a set of dates, then Active == 'In Progress', and if today's date is past all the dates, then Active == 'Past'. One part that makes this challenging is that I do not know how many individual games there will be, so I'm thinking something like this may work:

```
/* fetch row */
$firstrow = $result2->fetch_row();

$date1=date_create("$firstrow[0]");
$date2=date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```

But I don't know how many rows to make to test my last date, perhaps something with a

```
$row_count = $result->num_rows;
$datelast=date_create("$lastrow[$row-count-1]");
```

Not sure how to then implement and use this if it is the correct logic!

So does anyone know how I can compare each of these date rows to today's current date?

This is my initial select query:
**I've omitted some info from my image, to try to make the core logic of the problem easier, that's why there are some extra fields here**

```
//Create parlay select query    
$query = "SELECT
        u.first_name AS 'User First Name',
        u.last_name AS 'User Last Name',
        b.betting_site_name AS 'Betting Site',
        p.id AS 'Parlay ID',
        p.wager AS 'Wager',
        p.odds AS 'Odds',
        p.success AS 'Success',
        DATE_FORMAT(p.creationdate, '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'Date',
        pg.parlayid AS 'PG Parlay ID',
        SUM(p.wager * p.odds) AS Winnings
    FROM parlays p
    JOIN parlaygames pg ON pg.parlayid = p.id
    JOIN bonuses b ON p.bettingsiteid = b.id
    JOIN users u ON p.userid = u.id
    WHERE userid=$id
    GROUP BY p.id
    ORDER BY p.id DESC
    LIMIT 5";

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
```

This is my table creation code (and second while loop to get the individual games):

```
  <h2>Betting History</h2>
      <table class="table table-striped userwinnings">
        <tr>
          <th>Parlay Information</th>
          <th>Wager</th>
          <th>Active</th>
        </tr>
<?php

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $output = '<tr>';
                  $output .= '<td><table><tr><th>Date</th><th>Game</th><th>Bet Info</th></tr>';

                  $parlayid = $row['Parlay ID'];

                  $query3 = "SELECT 
                pg.parlayid AS ParlayID,
                g.date AS GameDate,
                ht.name AS HomeTeam,
                away.name AS AwayTeam,
                pg.betinfo AS BetInfo
            FROM parlaygames pg
            JOIN parlays p ON pg.parlayid = p.id
            JOIN games g ON pg.gameid = g.id
            JOIN teams ht ON g.home_team = ht.id
            JOIN teams away ON g.away_team = away.id
            JOIN users u ON u.id = p.userid
            WHERE p.id = $parlayid";

        $result3 = $mysqli->query($query3) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
           $gamescount = $result3->num_rows;
            $output .= '<tr>';
            $output .= '<td>'.$row3['GameDate'].'</td>';
            $output .= '<td>'.$row3['HomeTeam'].' vs '.$row3['AwayTeam'].'</td>';
            $output .= '<td>'.$row3['BetInfo'].'</td>';
            $output .= '</tr>';
        }                      

          $output .= '</table>';
                  $output .= '</td>';
                  $output .= '<td>'.$row['Wager'].'</td>';
                  $output .= '<td>'.$row['Active'].'</td>';
                  $output .= '</tr>';

                  echo $output;

}

?>
</table>
```

Comment: what is game start date and end date means field name and also filed name that can easy to create example query.

Comment: I don't have a specific start date and end date field names.... it  comes from the part of my code where there is a while loop inside my other while loop. I am unsure how many games there will be in a parlay, so how can I create those fields? Is there a way?

Comment: okay. you need to put condition on "g.date AS GameDate". or any other ?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by putting condition...which condition should I put? I just want the first date, but then also the last date as well. Which could end up being the same date in a 1-game parlay.

Comment: you need to set "past","feature","in process" on basis of g.date is that column will define oe any other table filed will be define that i am asking

Comment: By "condition" are you referring to an IF statement in my while loop?

Comment: "actually have a while loop inside a while loop (which is how I got multiple games to show on one row, but only one wager amount per row". No, this is a bad solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving this issue:

```
while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
           $gamescount = $result3->num_rows;

            /* seek to row no. 1 */
                $result4->data_seek(0);

                /* fetch row */
                $firstrow = $result4->fetch_row();

                $result4->data_seek($gamescount-1);
                $lastrow = $result4->fetch_row();

            $date1=date_create("$firstrow[1]");
            $date3=date_create("$lastrow[1]");
            $date2=date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
            $diff=date_diff($date3,$date2);

            $firstdate = $date3->format('Y-m-d');
            $lastdate = $date1->format('Y-m-d');
            $today = $date2->format('Y-m-d');

            if ($firstdate < $today && $today < $lastdate) {
                $active = "In Progress";
            } else if ($today > $lastdate) {
                $active = "Past";
            } else if ($today < $firstdate) {
                $active = "Future";
            }
```

I hope this logic can help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please replace these query

```
$query3 = "SELECT 
                pg.parlayid AS ParlayID,
                g.date AS GameDate,
                ht.name AS HomeTeam,
                away.name AS AwayTeam,
                pg.betinfo AS BetInfo
            FROM parlaygames pg
            JOIN parlays p ON pg.parlayid = p.id
            JOIN games g ON pg.gameid = g.id
            JOIN teams ht ON g.home_team = ht.id
            JOIN teams away ON g.away_team = away.id
            JOIN users u ON u.id = p.userid
            WHERE p.id = $parlayid";
```

With these one

```
$query3 = "SELECT 
                pg.parlayid AS ParlayID,
                g.date AS GameDate,
                IF((NOW() between MIN(g.date) AND MAX(g.date)),'In Progress',IF((MAX(g.date) > NOW()),'Future','Past')) as Acctive,
                ht.name AS HomeTeam,
                away.name AS AwayTeam,
                pg.betinfo AS BetInfo
            FROM parlaygames pg
            JOIN parlays p ON pg.parlayid = p.id
            JOIN games g ON pg.gameid = g.id
            JOIN teams ht ON g.home_team = ht.id
            JOIN teams away ON g.away_team = away.id
            JOIN users u ON u.id = p.userid
            WHERE p.id = $parlayid group by pg.parlayid";
```

Comment: Ok...I tried what you are saying, but it first broke my inside while loop, so only one game was showing and secondly, I wasn't able to see any "In Progress", "Future", or "Past" text in my Active column.

Comment: what happen mean it's affected on result set?

Comment: I don't understand your question...sorry Dhaval

Comment: i am saying that after execute these query what's wrong with your data can you little bit explain so i can solve it.

Comment: check i am updated code use that one i have added on group by